Why does attempt to detach an AWS network interface give permission error even with root login?
Tearing down a stage environment at work, and trying to detach a network interface with Administrator Access I got:

Failed to detach the network interface. API error: "You do not have permission to access the specified resource."

Trying again with the root login for the account I still got the same error, which really surprised me.
What could be the reason for this?

The "owner" attribute on the network interface listed my account ID.  But I noticed the "Requester-managed" attribute said "true" and the "requester" said "amazon-elb."  I found the ELB that was associated with the interface, deleted that, and the interface itself went away.
(Note this all was encountered on attempting a "terraform destroy" which timed out on attempting to delete the internet gateway.  When I tried to manually detach the internet gateway from the VPC, I got errors about network interfaces still in use which is what led me to the problem stated in the post.)
